# Spreadsheet that understands symbolic numbers

Tags: math, spreadsheet

I am about to do some calculations involving Pi. These would be easy to do in a spreadsheet, but I need the result to use Pi as a symbol - not as an approximated value.

Eg:

```
   A   B    C
1  =5  =Pi  =A1*B1
2  =2  =3.2 =A2+B2*C1*Pi
```

Should give:

```
   A   B    C
1  5   Pi   5*Pi
2  2   3.2  2+16*Pi^2
```

Does such a spreadsheet exist? I have the feeling that there will be so few tools that I cannot really be picky about the OS or price. If there are many of such tools, I would prefer GNU/Linux and free software.

Comment: You can define variable names in Excel. https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-variables-excel-55043.html

Comment: @EricShain But that will still cause the results to be approximative. I need the results to be exact (i.e. with symbols).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking at computer algebra system software or [symbolic algebra systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system). Wikipedia has an [extensive list of options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems). Few if any use a spreadsheet metaphor. Most are more notebook based. The big names are Mathematica and Maple, both of which are expensive. There are a lot of open source options such as [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) and [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org). Computer algebra systems can do more than just work with irrational numbers, they can solve equations and even do calculus symbolically. [This Mathematics SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-algebra-systems) may have useful information. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) can do some of this for you on the web. For example:
[image]

If you desperately want to stay with the spreadsheet metaphor, then [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/82c1/a616d983725bca9108ec25a8b85815874a03.pdf) might be of interest. Otherwise if you have some Python programming skills you could try [Pyspread](https://manns.github.io/pyspread/) which is a Python based spreadsheet that allows Python expressions in cells. In conjunction with [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), you chould get what you are looking for, but I haven't tried it myself.